# Dynamic equilibrium of planets

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, free-body-diagram, planets

We can describe statical equilibrium ( forces, moments ) in a cuboid $$ \Sigma F_x=0,\Sigma F_y=0,\Sigma F_z=0~$$       In dynamics can we describe similar dynamic equilibrium within an inertial cuboid box ( including gravitational forces, momenta etc.)?

In polar coordinates for the 2 Body problem we have 3 out of 4 forces ( centrifugal, tangential acceleration and Coriolis ) as mechanical and one as Newtonian gravity force. They can be solved using differential calculus.

For the 3 Body problem (say sun,earth, moon) in the plane of the ecliptic we have 3 gravity forces and the rest mechanical. Why cannot the 3 Body problem be solved using differential calculus?

Comment: @QMechanic: Thanks for the edit.